# Analyzing abnormal TCP/IP traffic: Sequential IP sequence numbers

Tags: ip, tcpdump, tcp, packet-sniffers

My professor told me that sequential IP sequence numbers is typical behavior of most IP stacks (and showed us examples of packet sniffers), but I thought IP sequence numbers are supposed to be randomly generated to avoid attacks?

Which one is it. I am taking a digital forensics class and I need to know how to differentiate "normal" tcp/ip stack traffic from "abnormal" traffic

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Solaris are the two major offenders of predictable IP id's.  I unfortunately have to run to a meeting right now so I can't explain but i'll try and remember to edit this with a better explanation when I get back.  Most other OS's were patched over a decade ago to have psuedo random starting IP id's.